# Is the system $L\{f[m,n]\}= c[m,n] f[m,n]$ shift invariant?

Tags: image-processing, convolution, linear-systems, 2d

$c[m,n]$ is the spatially varying gain.
My prof says that its not shift invariant. However if we put $m=m-k$ and $n=n-l$ we get $c[m-k,n-l] f[m-k,n-l]$ which is how a shift invariant system should behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Professor is right. What you have to do to show shift invariance is to compare the system's response to the input $f[m,n]$ to the response to the shifted input $f[m-k,n-l]$. If the response to the latter is just a shifted version of the original response then the system is shift invariant. However, this is not the case for the system $L\{f[m,n]\}=c[m,n]f[m,n]$ because when you shift the input $f[m,n]$ the gain $c[m,n]$ doesn't shift, so the responses are not shifted versions of each other.